# I try to fit my model but getting this error

Tags: tensorflow, keras

```
model.add(Flatten())
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(8))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse')
# This builds the model for the first time:
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=10
```

Error:

```
 ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-11-333e6d95c148> in <module>()
          5 model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mse')
          6 # This builds the model for the first time:
    ----> 7 model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=10)
    ValueError: Please provide as model inputs either a single array or a list of arrays.
```

Comment: This code seems a bit strange. You add flatten layer to the model before declaring it as a sequential model. What is your input layer? What is the shape of x_train?

Comment: You can try to trace an exception using links to raise https://fixexception.com/tensorflow/shapes-s-and-s-are-incompatible/

Comment: Looks like you passed invalid input shape or datatype to model. Tensorflow keras model expects input numpy array. Provide complete reproducible code. Thanks!